# how to generate AuthenticityToken on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I build the form tag by myself and when I post the form to server it give me a `InvalidAuthenticityToken` error, so I want to know how to add it in my own in current situation:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/crops/update" method="post">
  <input id="crop_x" name="crop_x" size="30" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="crop_y" name="crop_y" size="30" type="text" /><br />
  <input id="crop_w" name="crop_w" size="30" type="text" /><br />
   <input id="crop_h" name="crop_h" size="30" type="text" /><br />
  <input id="crop" name="crop" type="submit" value="Crop!" />
</form>
```

Response error is:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in CropsController#update 
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
Rails.root: /home/mlzboy/my/crop2
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There is a view helper called `form_authenticity_token` that returns the current session's authenticity token.

In your view.html.erb:

```
 <form action="/blah" method="POST">
   <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" type="hidden">
   <input name="first_name" type="text">
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, perhaps a more Rails idiomatic way would be ```<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>```

Answer (score 9):

This answer is first for *rails form token tag* in Google so to keep it simpler for future googling generations: just use `token_tag`, it's a helper defined in `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` that returns hidden input with `form_authenticity_token` as default value.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the token you have to use the method: `form_authenticity_token` as it was correctly noted by *@flitzwald*. Since it is rediced in a active controller's concern, you must include the module into a controller expclicitly before using as follows:

```
include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection

# use

def set_csrf_header
  response.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = form_authenticity_token
end
```